# jquery live() and $this

Tags: jquery

I'm having trouble with jQuery's live.  The div `one` should slidedown when the div `comment` of the same container div is clicked on.  What is happening is every div `one` is sliding down regardless of their containers. How do i fix this? I think it is the $this function but i don't know how to implement it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.one').hide();      
  $('.comment').live('click',function() {
    if ($('.one').is(':hidden')) {
      $('.one').slideDown('slow');
    }
  });
</script>

<?php
  for($i=0;$i<11;$i++) {
?>
<div class='container'>
  <a class='comment'>comment</a>
    <div class='one'>
      <textarea style='width:350px;height:100px'>Type text here</textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: `$('.one')` selects every element with class `one`, so that was to be expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case (from info provided) `.live()` is not neccessary, you can just use `.click()`.

The body of your function can look like this...

```
$one = $(this).next('.one'); //select the specific .one div you want
if ($one.is(':hidden')) {
    $one.slideDown('slow');
}
```

You want to target only the specific `.one` div you want to show... where currently you're targeting **every** `.one` div.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `next()`

```
 $('.one').hide();       
    $('.comment').live('click',function() {
       if ($(this).next('.one').is(':hidden')) {
          $(this).next('.one').slideDown('slow');
       }
 });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MYYex/6/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
  $('.comment').live('click',function() {
      $(this).siblings('.one').slideDown('slow');
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.one').hide();       
    $('.comment').live('click',function() {
     var sameone =  $(this).next('.one'); 
            if (sameone.is(':hidden')) {
            sameone.slideDown('slow');
            } 
        });
</script>
```